# a simple program to sort random numbers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

i just made a simple program that sorts random numbers in order:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

void swap(int &a,int &b){
    int temp=a;
    a=b;b=temp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    static int option;
    if(argv[1])option=atol(argv[1]);
    else option=0;
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    const int size=option;
    int array[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        array[i]=rand()%size;
    }

    //algorithm
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
            if(array[i]>array[j])swap(array[i],array[j]);
        }
    }
    //print
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you run it like this:

```
time ./a.exe (how much random number to generate)
```

it works fine upto 100000, but more than that gives me a seg fault error.
what am i doing wrong? is it because of insufficient memory??? or is the OS secretly doing something im not acknowledged of??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"is it because of insufficient memory??"*

Yes, your stack size is probably too small to hold this. Use

```
std::vector<int> array(size);
```

instead of

```
int array[size];
```

Comment: thanks. using vector fixed the problem. however, im getting slower results than using arrays. setting size=10000 i get 700ms with using vector when 400ms with an array. can you plz explain why??

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but accessing stack allocated memory might be faster than accessing memory allocated from the heap. This might well depend on OS and compiler.

Comment: @user2214712: Are you compiling with optimisations? If not, accessing the vector will involve calling functions, while accessing the array will be more direct. The times should be very similar if the optimiser inlines the function calls.

Comment: i have a new question, i heard that stack is generally faster to allocate than heap, so does int *array=new int[size] create an array on heap or stack? tried it and it gave me 2x faster results than using vector. it also did not give any seg faults.

Comment: @user2214712 `std::vector` doesn't do anything else than that. It's probably a question which optimization levels are used to compile your code, or if you run that in debug mode respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your stack size is too small, you can allocate the array in the heap like: `int *array = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int))`. Of course, you can use vector, but the vector has more complex encapsulation so the performance will be not very good.

Comment: _"... so the performance will be not very good."_ That's nonsense, `std::vector` provides as good performance than managing the memory on your own, at least for any decent modern c++ compiler.

Comment: I mean that the `std::vector` provides an encapsulation , such as `std::vector`'s member function `operator[]`, so there will be more function call